# Best Practices for storing a List of Values set using a NoSQL Database

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am working on a solution that uses a NoSQL backend.  My experience is traditionally with relational databases and would like to discuss the best way to store a list of values which may appear in a drop-down from the UI.  Traditonally, I would just create a table in my relational DB to store that small set of values and then my records would tie to a specific id representing that value.  A simple example of this is a Person table with all of my person records and a Hair color list of values with all the possible hair colors.  For each person, a hair color id from that hair color list of values table would be stored in the person record.  So a traditional foreign key relationship.

Most of these drop downs are not huge they are small sets (10s of fields) so storing them in their own container within Cosmos seems like overkill.  I thought I could also set these values as constants in my API model and manage the values that way.  However if those values change I need to do a new build of the API in order to expose those values.

Any thoughts on  best practices for how to handle in the NoSQL space?  Create a container in the NoSQL backend with the list of values, store the values as constants within my API model or something else?

Appreciate your time considering this question.

Comment: The overhead of small collections in CosmosDB has been mitigated somewhat by database level provisioning but I still wouldn't have lots of micro collections (IIRC the minimum RU per collection is still 100). What type of application is it? e.g. For a busy web site you probably don't want to hit Cosmos every time a user loads a page with the drop down so might look at caching with something like Redis (that can also offer persistence). NB: The `person` documents themselves should likely have the full hair colour - not a HairColourId

Comment: Martin - Thank you very much for this insight around micro collections. Where do you draw the line between storing the value in the person collection (such as hair color) and storing the ID?  Or should it always be the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these scenarios for reference data for UI elements I typically recommend storing all of this data in a single Cosmos container. Cosmos is schema agnostic so you can mix/match different schemas of data. If the data is <10GB use a dummy partition key (ie. /pk) with a single value and use a "type" property to distinguish among the different entity types for the data that match your UI elements. Fetch the data using a single query with the pk and then deserialize it into POCO's or whatever hydrates your UI using the type property to distinguish the different UI elements.

You can store this in a container that is part of a shared database. Minimum RU would be 100 RU/s with four containers in a database or 400 RU/s for dedicated container throughput. Which one you choose will depend on how much RU/s the query that fetches this data costs. You can easily get that by running the query in the Azure portal and looking at the query stats.